# Issue with prediction values from a random uniform forest object

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, predict

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("AU-Tum", 
"AU-Wac", "BE-Bra", "BE-Jal", "BR-Cax", "BR-Sa3", "CA-Ca1", "CA-Ca2", 
"CA-Ca3", "CA-Gro", "Ca-Man", "CA-NS1", "CA-NS2", "CA-NS3", "CA-NS4", 
"CA-NS5", "CA-NS6", "CA-NS7", "CA-Oas", "CA-Obs", "CA-Ojp", "CA-Qcu", 
"CA-Qfo", "CA-SF1", "CA-SF2", "CA-SF3", "CA-SJ1", "CA-SJ2", "CA-SJ3", 
"CA-TP1", "CA-TP2", "CA-TP4", "CN-Cha", "CN-Ku1", "CZ-Bk1", "De-Bay", 
"DE-Har", "DE-Tha", "DE-Wet", "DK-Sor", "FI-Hyy", "FI-Sod", "FR-Hes", 
"FR-Pue", "GF-Guy", "ID-Pag", "IL-Yat", "IT-Col", "IT-Lav", "IT-Non", 
"IT-Ro1", "IT-Ro2", "IT-Sro", "JP-Tak", "JP-Tef", "JP-Tom", "NL-Loo", 
"PT-Esp", "RU-Fyo", "SE-Abi", "SE-Fla", "SE-Nor", "SE-Sk1", "SE-Sk2", 
"SE-St1", "UK-Gri", "UK-Ham", "US-Blo", "US-Bn1", "US-Bn2", "Us-Bn3", 
"US-Dk3", "US-Fmf", "US-Fwf", "US-Ha1", "US-Ha2", "US-Ho1", "US-Ho2", 
"US-Lph", "US-Me1", "US-Me3", "US-Nc2", "US-NR1", "US-Oho", "US-Sp1", 
"US-Sp2", "US-Sp3", "US-Syv", "US-Umb", "US-Wcr", "US-Wi0", "US-Wi1", 
"US-Wi2", "US-Wi4", "US-Wi8", "VU-Coc", "Austin", "Caxiuana", 
"Mae Klong", "Niwot Ridge", "Sky Oaks old", "Sky Oaks young", 
"Sodankylä", "Tomakomai", "Yenisey Abies", "Yenisey Betula", 
"Yenisey Mixed"), class = "factor"), P = c(1241.59999960661, 
1282.40000277758, 0, 895, 0, 960.399999260902, 988.300011262298, 
778.211069688201, 0, 676.725008800626, 1750.51986303926, 1614.11541634798, 
951.847023338079, 1119.3682884872, 1112.38984390156, 1270.65773075982, 
1234.72262170166, 1338.46096616983, 1136.69287367165, 1265.46480803983
), Te = c(9.20406423444821, 9.58323018294185, NaN, 12.1362462834136, 
NaN, 10.6474634506736, 10.2948508957069, 11.3363996068107, NaN, 
11.9457507949986, 9.10006221322572, 7.65505467142961, 8.21480062559674, 
8.09251754304318, 8.466220758789, 8.48094407814006, 8.77304120569444, 
8.31727518543397, 8.80921738865237, 9.04091478341757), Y = c(2172.34112930298, 
2479.44521586597, 1027.63470042497, 2342.35314202309, 868.4010617733, 
1157.13594430499, 1118.60130960867, 1100.47051284742, 1072.57190890331, 
1228.25697739795, 2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 2269.1387550775, 
2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 2359.51909126411, 
2488.39004804939, 461.398994384333, 567.150629704352)), .Names = c("ID", 
"P", "Te", "Y"), row.names = 307:326, class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to set-up a leave one ID out cross validation for a random uniform forest analysis. Basically, I want a loop where each time I removed data with same ID and I train my model with the other IDs. I then test my model by doing a prediction on the data I removed for the training. I have followed what it is suggested in this post(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109340/leave-one-subject-out-cross-validation-in-caret). Therefore, I got something like that:

```
library (randomUniformForest)
df<-na.omit(df)
subs <- unique(df$ID)
model_these <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(subs))
test_these <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(subs))
for(i in seq_along(subs)){
  model_these[[i]] <- which(df$ID != subs[i])
names(model_these) <- paste0("ID", subs)
test_these[[i]] <- which(df$ID == subs[i])
names(test_these) <- paste0("ID", subs)
svmFit <- randomUniformForest(Y~ P+Te, 
                              data= df,
                                importance = T,
                              ntree = 100, 
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                                index = model_these, 
                                                classProbs =  TRUE))
ruf_pred = predict(object = svmFit, X = df, index= test_these)
}
```

The loop seems to be working, however the predicted values are all the same which obviously does not make any sense.

```
 [1] 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212 1940.212
[16] 1940.212 1940.212
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use a number of arguments that are specific to the `train` method of the `caret` package, which is what the example you linked refers to. The `randomUniformForest` does not accept a `trControl` argument, for instance.

For your case, the following lines should work:

```
library (randomUniformForest)
df$prediction <- NA
for(id in unique(df$ID)){
  train.df <- df[df$ID != id,]
  test.df <- df[df$ID == id,c("P", "Te")]
  svmFit <- randomUniformForest(Y ~ P+Te, 
                                data = train.df,
                                importance = T,
                                ntree = 100)
  ruf_pred = predict(object = svmFit, X = test.df)
  df$prediction[df$ID == id] <- ruf_pred
}
```

Note, though, that you're working with very few observations - the `randomUniformForest` method issues an according warning - and the predictions are pretty inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is just a test dataset. I have more datapoints and more predictors in my real data. One question: Why do we need to specify `c("P", "Te")` in the test.df?

Comment: The `c("P", "Te")` ensures that only these two variables remain in the test data frame. We do this because `?predict.randomUniformForest` says that argument `X` should be "a data frame or matrix containing new data (without response values)". It seems that if you pass a data frame with anything different than the predictors, `predict` just uses the first two columns, regardless of their names.